# How can I disable migrations like that never enabled

Tags: migration, code-first

I need to disable migrations on my code first project. I just run`enable-migrations` command. But now I need to disable migrations on my project. I need another changes to my project and after these I will enable migrations because now I got errors on my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite easy. Just delete the Migrations folder. Be advised that this is not the same as dropping the existing database and creating a new one.

Comment: Glad to be of service!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists());